# how to link stylesheets in laravel-9?

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, laravel-9

I tried to connect the style.css file, but I encountered some problems sometimes and sometimes it works
the way

I created a folder

> layouts

Inside it I created a file

> app.blade.php

But when you open "inspect" from Google Chrome
The code appears like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFlHc.png)

**I want the head page to be at the top**

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share the code for your `app.blade.php` file?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).